# pytest: initialize mocker class once and use for multiple tests

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

Currently my tests are starting to follow a certain pattern:

```
class Test_DateRow: 
    def test_make_calender_year(self, mocker):
        mocker.patch.object(retailtableclasses.DateRow, '__init__', return_value=None)
        daterow = retailtableclasses.DateRow()
        daterow.DATE = "9999-01-01"
        assert daterow.make_calender_year() == "9999"


    def test_make_month(self, mocker):
        mocker.patch.object(retailtableclasses.DateRow, '__init__', return_value=None)
        daterow = retailtableclasses.DateRow()
        daterow.MONTH_NUMBER_ISO = 1
        assert daterow.make_month() == "January"
```

before I continue with this pattern and start initializing mocker patches, would it be possible to initialize `mocker.patch.object` and `daterow` once and use it in the calendar_year and make_month tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it work for you to extract the logic into a fixture?

```
import pytest

class Test_DateRow:

    @pytest.fixture
    def daterow(self, mocker):
        mocker.patch.object(retailtableclasses.DateRow, '__init__', return_value=None)
        daterow = retailtableclasses.DateRow()

        yield daterow 

        # Put any potential teardown logic here.
    
    def test_make_calender_year(self, daterow):
        daterow.DATE = "9999-01-01"
        assert daterow.make_calender_year() == "9999"
```